# GraphQL mutation not returning a newly registered user that is successfully create in postgresql

Tags: typescript, postgresql, graphql, knex.js, typegraphql

I am writing a graphql mutation for registering new users. This mutation should return an array of errors or a User object. For some reason when there are errors. The mutation is returning them. But when I successfully register a new user, the mutation is returning null but the user is being registered successfully in Postgresql

The mutations returns a UserResponse object

```
 @ObjectType()
        class UserResponse {
          @Field(() => [FieldError], { nullable: true })
          errors?: FieldError[];
        
          @Field(() => User, { nullable: true })
          user?: User;
        }

This is my mutation

    let user:User;
        try{
          const response = await (em as EntityManager)
.createQueryBuilder(User)
.getKnexQuery()
.insert({
          email: options.email,
          password: hashedPassword,
          name: options.name,
          role: options.role,
          created_at: new Date(),
          updated_at: new Date()
})
.returning("*");
          user = response[0];
          } catch(err){
            console.log("ERROR",err)
            if (err.code === '23505'){
              console.log("DUPLICATE EMAIL");
                return {
                    errors: [
                        {
                            field:'email',
                            message:'This email is already in use. Please use another email address.'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
          req.session.userId = user.id;
    
    
        return {
          user,
        };
```

The user is successfully registered and also the cookie is created in the frontend but in the api response I am getting:

```
 {
    "errors": null,
    "user": null,
    "__typename": "UserResponse"
}
```

I tried implementing the same logic but instead of using Knex, I used persist and flush and it works as intended with the user being returned.

To build this mutation I am using type-graphql and mikro-orm/postgresql

These are my ouputs when registration is successful.

Server:

```
    {
  id: 209,
  created_at: 2022-01-27T20:13:52.000Z,
  updated_at: 2022-01-27T20:13:52.000Z,
  name: 'dasdasdasds',
  email: 'dasdasdaddas@s.com',
  role: 'agent',
  password: '$argon2',  
  points: null
}
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2032-01-25T20:13:51.499Z,
    originalMaxAge: 315360000000,
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: 'lax',
    secure: false
  },
  userId: 209
}
```

Front-end

```
{
  "errors": null,
  "user": null,
  "__typename": "UserResponse"
}
```

Comment: Can you please format your code with proper indentation so that we can understand it more clearly?

Comment: I formatted it.

Comment: Did you check your logs, are you certain that `console.log("ERROR",err)` is not executed?

Comment: Yes as I mentioned, the user is successfully being uploaded and the cookie is being created. I am starting to wonder whether there is some sort of bug with Knex query builder but i can't identify it.

Comment: The `req.session.userId` cookie is created in your code even when there was an error. You really should put an `else throw err;` on the `if (err.code === '23505')`.

Comment: Can you please `console.log(response)` and show what result you're getting?

Comment: I will add the screenshot of the ouput but how would this req.session.userId be executed if we are returning the error before the block after it. Supposedly there is an error. Also, I checked when an error occurs no cookies gets returned.

Comment: @Bergi Added outputs